# Best way to organize Rails controller index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, namespaces

Our app can track clients who walk in to our clinic without an appointment. We started with a simple WalkIn model and WalkInsController.

Then we added another type of walk-in, then another ... so now our #index action has to filter between four different walk-in types and sometimes treat them differently.

The other REST actions (besides #show) are mostly the same between types, but might have some minor differences. We also have a few non-REST methods that don't really fit anywhere else.

So, at minimum, this #index action needs to be tamed.

First thought: I'll namespace walk_ins just for #index:

```
namespace :walk_ins do
  get 'clinic'      => 'clinic_walk_ins#index',      :as => :clinic
  get 'group'       => 'group_walk_ins#index',       :as => :group
  get 'assessment'  => 'assessment_walk_ins#index',  :as => :assessment
  get 'initial'     => 'initial_walk_ins#index',     :as => :initial
end

resources :walk_ins, except: [ :index ] do
  member do
    get :eligible_initial_appointments
    patch :mark_follow_up_as_completed
  end
  collection do
    get :follow_up_due
  end
end
```

So I'd create `WalkIns::InitialWalkInsController`, etc., for the #index action for initial walk-ins, and I'll leave top-level `WalkInsController` for the rest of the resources.

But since the namespace is the same as the top-level controller -- `walk-ins` -- I can't do `walk_ins/initial`, because Rails will treat it as `walk_ins#show` and say it can't find a WalkIn with ID "show".

I could simply change the name of the namespace, but `walk_ins` really makes the most sense.

Second pass -- embed all resource routes into the namespace:

```
namespace :walk_ins do
  get 'clinic'      => 'clinic_walk_ins#index',      :as => :clinic
  get 'group'       => 'group_walk_ins#index',       :as => :group
  get 'assessment'  => 'assessment_walk_ins#index',  :as => :assessment
  get 'initial'     => 'initial_walk_ins#index',     :as => :initial

  resources :walk_ins, except: [ :index ] do
    member do
      get :eligible_initial_appointments
      patch :mark_follow_up_as_completed
    end
    collection do
      get :follow_up_due
    end
  end
end
```

This works, and it's great to have a discrete controller for each type of walk_in#index.

But now every resource that isn't index has to be inside `walk_ins/walk_ins`.

For example, to edit WalkIn 3, the URL is:

`/walk_ins/walk_ins/3/edit`

That seems like ... not what I want.

What is the best way to organize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can move all walk_ins filter inside collection block like this

```rb
resources :walk_ins, except: [ :index ] do
 member do
  get :eligible_initial_appointments
  patch :mark_follow_up_as_completed
 end

 collection do
  get :follow_up_due
  get 'clinic', controller: 'walk_ins/clinic_walk_ins', action: 'index', as: 'clinic'
  get 'group', controller: 'walk_ins/group_walk_ins', action: 'index', as: 'group'
  get 'assessment', controller: 'walk_ins/assessment_walk_ins', action: 'index', as: 'assessment'
  get 'initial', controller: 'walk_ins/initial_walk_ins', action: 'index', as: 'initial'
 end
end
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was so convinced I was going to need to namespace, I forgot to just add the routes to the collection directly.